# java.io.NotSerializableException using Primefaces and Weblogic

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2, weblogic

I'm using Primefaces 6.1 running on a clustered WebLogic Server (Mojarra 2.2.8) Version: 12.2.1.3.0 and during the session replication i'm getting the following exception:

```
<Jan 30, 2018 4:08:08,727 PM CET> <Error> <Cluster> <BEA-003144> <All session objects should be serializable to replicate. Check the objects in the session. Failed to replicate a non-serializable object in context /app.
java.rmi.MarshalException: failed to marshal create(Lweblogic.rmi.spi.HostID;ILweblogic.cluster.replication.ROID;Ljava.io.Serializable;); nested exception is: 
java.io.NotSerializableException: org.primefaces.model.SortMeta
at weblogic.rjvm.BasicOutboundRequest.marshalArgs(BasicOutboundRequest.java:100)
at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicRemoteRef.invoke(BasicRemoteRef.java:297)
at weblogic.cluster.replication.RemoteReplicationServicesInternalImpl_12213_WLStub.create(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1191.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.primefaces.model.SortMeta
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:766)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor31.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

> 

JSF component binding is never used in the application. Looking at the Primefaces source I can see that the model SortMeta (does not implements Serializable) is only used in the DataTable component.

The view state saving method has to be server side.

How to solve or avoid this exception?

**EDIT:**

Problem was caused by the "new" datatable attribute multiViewState.

https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=54138&p=164132

Class SortMeta is now Serializable:
https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/3272

Comment: I would check beans attached to the session, as far as I remember weblogic also replicates beans unless they are request scoped. So somewhere in your code you might use a primefaces class

Comment: @HRgiger The only reference is to a Primefaces model TreeNode but it implements Serializable... all the rest is String, boolean etc... The datatable is used of course in the JSF facelets. Thank you

Comment: Please create a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.  And did you try 6.1.12 or 6.2-RC1? And checked for a newer version of Mojarra?

Comment: You should provide some Example code. As the Exception clearly states, there is a try to `serialize` something `unserializable`. This can be the Bean itself, a property of the bean, or a property of an complex-attribute of the bean.

Comment: @dognose I tried to programmatically serialize all the beans (using a commandButton) in different scenario without any exception. I will see if I can provide a minimal code example. Thank you